# Break point are not hits on View but working fine in controller. Why?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, debugging

While running my MVC3 application in debug or release mode, breakpoints are working fine in Controllers but not in Views.
Unable to find the solution.
Please help.

Comment: Where are you setting the breakpoint in the file? Make sure the breakpoint is placed on a line which contains C# code (e.g. inside the Razor syntax).

Comment: Yup, breakpoints are on the c# code.

Comment: Hate to ask the obvious but I have been bitten by this issue: are you sure your break points are in the right view? (views with similar names and structure in different folders threw me off).

Comment: yes they are at correct place.

Comment: this might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18495698/visual-studio-does-not-allow-breakpoints-in-mvc-views

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to put any debug points in View . You can do only in Controllers and Models.

Inorder to debug view , put a break point in the controller action where , the view is rendered and continue with clicking on F11.

This wll help you in debugging the corresponding view..

Hope this helps..

Comment: It **is** possible to debug views too.

Comment: @Ken2k..you can not exactly debug view..but you can see how the control is flowing in the code and also if your view contains any C# Code..yes..you can well debug..

Comment: I tried that too by pressing F11 after the controller action rendering view but it redirect to browsers not to view....

Answer (score 0):

You have to open up the corresponding file that comes up in the Visual studio. Usually it will be named blank. If you are using IE10 then you can debug using VS. If you are using chrome then within chrome developer tool itself you can debug.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link [Setting Breakpoints in MVC ASPX Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009168/any-way-to-set-breakpoints-in-mvc3-aspx-views)

> Contrary to popular belief you can actually set breakpoints in ASPX
>   views.
>
> In Visual Studio you can navigate your cursor at the desired location,
>   hit F9 (Toggle Breakpoint) and it's done.
>
> It can be done in Razor and ASPX views, and even in ASPX pages (in
>   WebForms).
>
> If you CAN'T set the breakpoint there that means that the given part
>   is not C# code but the HTML part instead. You can't set breakpoints at
>   parts like , you can only set it between the silly <% and %>
>   parts (in Razor it is @{...}, @(...) or simply @...).
>
> Also make sure your application is built, and the debugger is attached
>   to the server instance (if it's on IIS express switch to Development
>   Server in the project properties, and vica-versa).
>
> Stop the development server instances on the taskbar, rebuild your
>   project and start it again. It should hit the breakpoint just fine.

Comment: As the breakpoints are hits on the controller so I think there is no issue related to IIS.