# I can't set breakpoint in razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, debugging, razor

I know it's possible to set breakpoints in a MVC Razor view but something got wrong and it's not working anymore..

I tried to restart visual studio 2013 and to change some options of Debugging. Have you got any suggestion?

Comment: you mean it does not hit it or just you cant set one?

Comment: Try clean\rebuild your solution

Comment: Check the debug tab and make sure breakpoints are enabled.

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for, but... If there's enough server-side code in the view to *be* meaningfully stepped through in a debugger then it sounds like that code should be moved to the view model.

Comment: @Dejan.S: I can't set by hitting neither by pressing F9

Comment: Do you target actual code? Can you show a screen?

Comment: @Vladimirs: I cannot believe it.. but cleaning worked :D

Comment: make sure you setting your breakpoint within Razor context (you won't be able to debug html/js/etc) - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009168/setting-breakpoints-in-mvc-aspx-views

Comment: @Vladimirs: can you change the comment into an answer? Otherwise this question will become auto deleted in some time..

Comment: @Bart: what do you mean? He can delete the comment and put an answer. But I also think that giving a reusable by other user answer is more important than avoiding duplication between comment and answer. Do you agree?

Comment: @Bart: ah, now I understand.. no, this answer of him was working: "Try clean\rebuild your solution". The other question is not related to my problem

Comment: Another Web failure from Microsoft. 
Any alternatives that are not razor and not javascript?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thanks to Vladimirs I could find a solution.

I had to Clean and Rebuild the whole solution. I tried a simple rebuild before but it didn't worked.

Comment: Didn't work for me.
What did work: close Visual Studio and re-open it.

Comment: Restarting Visual studio, then full clean/rebuild worked for me as well.

Comment: These solutions didn't work for me, but because I wanted to check the `images` model passed into the View, I set my breakpoint on the `return View("Images", images);` statement from within the Controller.

Comment: Yep, close and reopen VS

Comment: VS 2022 with Razor Components.  Close Reopen VS, clean solution then rebuild solution.

Answer (score 3):

instead of setting breakpoint in visual studio,write this line of code in your razor page:

```
@{
 System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
 }
```

Comment: didn't work, also it's System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

Comment: @ is neccessary to run c# in razor.

Comment: you missed the 's' at the end of Diagnostics

Answer (score 1):

use block code

```
@{
   if (condition)
       var xx = "something";
}
```

instead of

```
@if (condition)
   var xx = "something";
```