# Visual studio 2017 breakpoint in view issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have an issue with VS 2017 entreprise edition, in MVC project it doesn't hit breakpoints in rasor views (.cshtml). I have this issue only with views, the breakpoint gets hit in controllers and other classes.

The same project loaded in VS 2015 works fine.

I already googled it but didn't find anything related to this issue. Any idea !

I found a part of the problem but still not all the solution.

My OS (windows 8.1) is in french and VS 2017 in English, in this configuration it doesn't work, breakpoints in views aren't hit, when I switch VS langauge to french it works. it seems very weird

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26387136/i-cant-set-breakpoint-in-razor-view), [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18495698/visual-studio-does-not-allow-breakpoints-in-mvc-views), [related](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/issues/360) etc etc

Comment: Maybe out of sync with IIS Express (Breakpoint icon is empty with an asterisk?)

Comment: I use IIS (not IIS Express) and yes it's the classical message it says the breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document, but I don't understand why it happens only with views